# v-data-table(vuetify) does not work on ie11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, vuetify.js, babeljs, cdn, lighttpd

I use vuejs with lighttpd

Therefore, npm, require and import cannot be used.

I want to use vuetify's v-data-table

Footer number does not appear in ie11

Can you solve this?

I used babel-polyfill

The cdn is:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.8.7/polyfill.min.js

If cdn is wrong, let me know what is correct.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please check my reply, whether it solved the problem? If not, can you post enough code to reproduce the problem? it is better to capture a screenshot and let us know the issue clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CDN IE polyfill](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.8.7/polyfill.min.js) is correct. please check your code and try to add the polyfill reference before the vuetify reference. And, check the Vue **data** property, we could set the data property as below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.8.7/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data: {
                singleSelect: false,
                selected: [],
                headers: [
                    {
                        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                        align: 'start',
                        sortable: false,
                        value: 'name',
                    },
                    { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
                    { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
                    { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
                    { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
                    { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
                ],
                desserts: [
                    {
                        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                        calories: 159,
                        fat: 6.0,
                        carbs: 24,
                        protein: 4.0,
                        iron: '1%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                        calories: 237,
                        fat: 9.0,
                        carbs: 37,
                        protein: 4.3,
                        iron: '1%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Eclair',
                        calories: 262,
                        fat: 16.0,
                        carbs: 23,
                        protein: 6.0,
                        iron: '7%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Cupcake',
                        calories: 305,
                        fat: 3.7,
                        carbs: 67,
                        protein: 4.3,
                        iron: '8%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Gingerbread',
                        calories: 356,
                        fat: 16.0,
                        carbs: 49,
                        protein: 3.9,
                        iron: '16%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Jelly bean',
                        calories: 375,
                        fat: 0.0,
                        carbs: 94,
                        protein: 0.0,
                        iron: '0%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Lollipop',
                        calories: 392,
                        fat: 0.2,
                        carbs: 98,
                        protein: 0,
                        iron: '2%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Honeycomb',
                        calories: 408,
                        fat: 3.2,
                        carbs: 87,
                        protein: 6.5,
                        iron: '45%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Donut',
                        calories: 452,
                        fat: 25.0,
                        carbs: 51,
                        protein: 4.9,
                        iron: '22%',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'KitKat',
                        calories: 518,
                        fat: 26.0,
                        carbs: 65,
                        protein: 7,
                        iron: '6%',
                    },
                ],
            } 
    })
</script>
```

And then, add the following style to fix the [Data Table footer issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9790):

```
<style> 
    .v-data-footer__select {
        flex-basis: auto;
    }

        .v-data-footer__select .v-select {
            flex-basis: 50px;
        }

            .v-data-footer__select .v-select .v-select__selections {
                flex-basis: auto;
                min-width:25px;
            }

    .v-list-item__content {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        min-width: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

IE browser result ([the whole sample code](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/JjYaPxa)):

[image]